# Chrome API for adding external cloud storage to a chromebook that isn't drive

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os, cloud-storage

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to add other storage options to chromeOS. By default you get your internal location (downloads), your google drive and your connected SD cards and external drives.

[image: Google's Files App]

In the Files App you can see all of them in the left column. I am wondering if there is an API / solution that would allow for extra services to be listed there.

I for instance have an owncloud server running. Can I integrate "Owncloud drive" to the Files App? Would it be possible via an extra extension? Or is there an API t make this easier?

I tried to google for it but I couldn't find much.

Comment: This is currently a feature in development, but not close to completion it seems: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=248427